# Running "dnx ef migrations add" twice or more doesn't create blank Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework 7 RC1

I run the following

```
dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration

dnx ef migration add MyCustomMigration
```

I was expecting MyCustomMigration to have empty `Up` and `Down` method but instead it has

Up:

```
 migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_XXX_XXX", table: "tbl_XXX");
 migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
     name: "FK_XXX_XXX"           ....
     onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Down:

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_XXX_XXX", table: "tbl_XXX");
 migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
     name: "FK_XXX_XXX"           ....
     onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

If I run the command more than two times it does exactly the same

```
dnx ef migration add MyCustomMigration2
```

creates the same Migration File with the exact same contents

I want to create an empty migration file so I can put in my custom migrations. However it seems there is a bug there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like issue [#3751](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3751) which should be fixed in the [nightly builds](http://myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext).